# Infinite CW Complex

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I recently picked up Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*, and I'm struggling with the following notion in his definition of a CW complex in Chapter 0:

> (3) One can either stop this inductive process at a finite stage, setting $X = X^n$ for some $n < \infty$, or one can continue indefinitely, setting $X = \bigcup_\alpha X^n$. In the latter case $X$ is given the weak topology: A set $A \subset X$ is open (or closed) iff $A \cap X^n$ is open (or closed) in $X^n$ for each $n$.

I'm having trouble getting a grip of the case where we don't stop the procedure at a finite final dimension. From a purely set-theoretical perspective, each $X^n$ is not contained in $X^m$ for $m > n$, since each $X^n$ is formally constructed as a quotient of $X^{n-1}$ and some $n$-discs. Therefore the union $\bigcup_n X^n$ is literally just a disjoint union of separate skeletons, which doesn't seem to be interesting or the point of the construction.

I feel like the real idea is to identify $X^n$ as a subspace of $X^{n-1}$ for all $n$ and then take the union. But how would we formalize this? It seems like there's going to be a lot of relabeling involved. I remember seeing a similar sort of construction in algebra that used the notion of a direct limit--is that the right way to look at this too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$\pi:X_{n-1}\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\mathcal{E}} D^n\rightarrow X_n$$
be the quotient map where $\mathcal{E}$ indexes the $n$-cells of $X$. Then we check that the restriction $\pi|_{X_{n-1}}$ is injective.

Let $A\subset X_{n-1}$. Then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(A))=A\sqcup\bigsqcup_{i\in\mathcal{E}}\varphi_i^{-1}(A)$, where $\varphi_i:S^{n-1}\rightarrow X_{n-1}$, $i\in\mathcal{E}$, is the attaching map of the $i^{th}$ cell. If $A$ is closed in $X$, then $\varphi_i^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $S^{n-1}$, and hence also in $D^n$. It folllows that if $A\subseteq X$ is closed, then $\pi^{-1}(\pi(A))$ is closed in $X_{n-1}\sqcup\bigsqcup_{\mathcal{E}} D^n$, and so $\pi(A)$ is closed in $X_n$, which is a quotient of the disjoint union. Thus:

> The inclusion $X_{n-1}\hookrightarrow X_n$ is a closed embedding.

By induction we have that $X_n$ is closed in each $X_m$, $m\geq n$. If $m\leq n$, then $X_m\cap X_n=X_m$ is closed. Since $X=colim\;X_n$ carries the weak topology with respect to its skeleta we see that $X_n$ is embedded in $X$ as a closed subspace.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what $colim X_n$ means?

Comment: I mean $colim\;X_n=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}X_n$ as sets, topologised so that $A\subseteq colim\;X_n$ is open (closed) if and only if $A\cap X_n$ is open (closed) for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. There is nothing fancy here: it is just notation for the weak topology.

Comment: Got it - I'm still confused about the formal details of the induction. In order to give a union the weak topology we need to have an infinite sequence $X_0 \subset X_1 \subset X_2 \subset \cdots$ of spaces contained in each other. But even with induction, we can't quite get this because as soon as we introduce the $n$th space $X_n$ we have to replace $X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1}$ with their images under the embedding $X_{n-1} \to X_n$. So it seems like those subset chains can only ever be finite. How do we get around this?

Comment: Also I see why the inclusion $X_{n-1} \hookrightarrow X_n$ is closed, but can you explain why it's also an embedding?

Comment: Nick, an continuous closed injection is an embedding.

Comment: During the induction we only ever need the chains to be finite, but arbitrarily large. Then $X_n$ certainly maps injectively into $X=\bigcup X_k$, and given any $k$ we have that $X_n\cap X_k$ is closed in $X_k$ (it will be all of $X_k$ if $k\leq n$). Thus $X_n$ is closed in $X$, since $X$ has the weak topology.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $X^n$ and a disjoint union of $n+1$ balls $B=\sqcup_{i\in I} B_i$, and maps $f_i\colon \partial B_i\to X^n$, we construct $X^{n+1}$ by quotienting out by the equivalence relation generated by $b\sim f(b)$ for all $b\in \partial B$.

The answer to your question is that two distinct points of $X_n$ are never related by this equivalence relation.  A point $x\in X^n$ may be related to several $b\in B$ which map to $x$ under their respective boundary maps. The entire equivalence class of $x$ is then just $$\{x\}\cup \bigcup_{i\in I} f_i^{-1}(x).$$

Thus we get a sequence of nested inclusions $$X^0\subseteq X^1\subseteq X^2\cdots$$
and we may define $X$ as the union of these.

Comment: This makes sense, but my confusion stems from the fact that $X^n$ isn't *literally* a subset of $X^{n+1}$, although it does have a natural embedding into $X^{n+1}$. In order to get strict subset inclusions like you've written we'd need to do an infinite amount of relabeling, and I'm not sure how to get around that/formalize that.

Comment: You could take the disjoint union of the $X^n$ and then generate an equivalence relation by the embeddings: so $x\in X^n$ is equivalent to $\iota_n(x)\in X^{n+1}$.  Here $\iota_n$ is the embedding constructed above.

Comment: Say $X$ is the quotient of the disjoint union by that equivalence relation. Is the quotient topology on $X$ also the weak topology on $X$ coherent with $X^0, X^1,X^2,\ldots$ viewed as subsets of $X$, like the definition requires?

Comment: A subset of the quotient is open if and only if  its preimage in the disjoint union is open, by definition of quotient topology.  A subset of the disjoint union is open if and only if its intersection with each $X^n$ is open, by definition of the topology on a disjoint union.  So yes this is the same topology.